# How do I require MFA only when it has been set up?

Tags: ubuntu, sshd, pam, google-authenticator

I'd like to require every user to use MFA with Google Authenticator. Each time I add a new user, I want to allow them to log in using their SSH key only once, and upon login require them to create a secret key by running GAuth setup in their `.bash_login`. This will create `~/.google_authenticator` in their home directory. I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-ssh-on-ubuntu-16-04) (Ctrl+F "Another method to force the creation") to set up my `sshd_config` and `pam.d`. Here they are, with comments removed:

**`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`**

```
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no

AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

AllowUsers me him
PermitRootLogin no
MaxStartups 15
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

**`/etc/pam.d/sshd`**

```
# Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth

account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

session    required     pam_loginuid.so

session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

@include common-session

session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

session    required     pam_limits.so

session    required     pam_env.so # [1]

session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password

auth required pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

From what I understand, the "nullok" on the last line means that if no secret key has been set up, nothing is required to satisfy that auth requirement. But when I try to log in with a user who has no secret key configured, I get something like the following:

```
$ ssh him@my_device
him@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (keyboard-interactive).
```

Once the `.google_authenticator` file is created, login should proceed fine. How do I allow this kind of login as long as `.google_authenticator` is not present?

By the way, this is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed an update to the project's README adding information about the `nullok` option.

```
PAM requires at least one `SUCCESS` answer from a module, and `nullok`
causes this module to say `IGNORE`. This means that if this option is
used at least one other module must have said `SUCCESS`. One way to do
this is to add `auth required pam_permit.so` to the end of the PAM
config.
```

from:
https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam/commit/5e804ec11104a1ab17ce02d0681130ded037f39b